# Concatenate Two pandas Dataframes (A & B) in an Alternating Pattern of Columns (A,-B-A, A-B-A)

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have two dataframes that I am trying to concatenate together. For the sake of clarity, let's call these dataframes A and B. What I want to do is to concatenate alternating columns from each dataframe in a repeating A-B-A, A-B-A pattern. What I mean by that is this: I want the first column to come from dataframe A, the next from dataframe B, then dataframe A again; then the pattern should repeat A-B-A.

Below are sample of dataframes (A and B) and the expected output.

```
data1 = {'ipt_v1': {'V7': 24.588074000000002, 'V4': 22.116738}, 
         'ipt_v2': {'V7': 4.958045, 'V4': 4.726775}}


data2 = {('ipt_v1', 'l'): {'V7': 24.251368038901415, 'V4': 21.806257204224853},
         ('ipt_v1', 'u'): {'V7': 24.92477996109859, 'V4': 22.427218795775136},
         ('ipt_v2', 'l'): {'V7': 4.901618779535504, 'V4': 4.665580151848285},
         ('ipt_v2', 'u'): {'V7': 5.014471220464495, 'V4': 4.787969848151715}}


# expected out
output = {('ipt_v1', 'l'): {'V7': 24.251368038901415, 'V4': 21.806257204224853},
          ('ipt_v1', 'm'): {'V7': 24.588074000000002, 'V4': 22.116738},
          ('ipt_v1', 'u'): {'V7': 24.92477996109859, 'V4': 22.427218795775136},
          ('ipt_v2', 'l'): {'V7': 4.901618779535504, 'V4': 4.665580151848285},
          ('ipt_v2', 'm'): {'V7': 4.958045, 'V4': 4.726775},
          ('ipt_v2', 'u'): {'V7': 5.014471220464495, 'V4': 4.787969848151715}}
```

Additionally, I have included a function that is intended to give the expected output. The part I need some help with in regard to the function relates to `# alternating the columns`

```
def combo(data1, data2):
    rws = data1
    ciws = data2
    
    rws.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['m'],rws.columns])
    rws = rws.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
    
    output = pd.concat([ciws, rws], axis=1)
    
    # alternating the columns
    output = (output[list(sum(zip(ciws.columns, rws.columns), ()))])
    return output

# call the function
output = combo(data1, data2)
print(output)
```

Comment: Do you really need A-B-A for any input? Because it looks like sorting the `concat` might give the output you want (if needed to define a particular order you can use ordered `Categorical` data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insert`, which takes position (integer), name and values as argument. In your case you want to insert columns at every third position from the first dataframe starting with column 1:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data1 = {('ipt_v1', 'm'): {'V7': 24.588074000000002, 'V4': 22.116738}, 
         ('ipt_v2', 'm'): {'V7': 4.958045, 'V4': 4.726775}}


data2 = {('ipt_v1', 'l'): {'V7': 24.251368038901415, 'V4': 21.806257204224853},
         ('ipt_v1', 'u'): {'V7': 24.92477996109859, 'V4': 22.427218795775136},
         ('ipt_v2', 'l'): {'V7': 4.901618779535504, 'V4': 4.665580151848285},
         ('ipt_v2', 'u'): {'V7': 5.014471220464495, 'V4': 4.787969848151715}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df = df2.copy()
i = 1
for c in df1.columns:
    df.insert(i, c, df1[c])
    i += 3
```

In your case you could also achive the same result using a simple sort:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
sorted_columns = sorted(df.columns)
df = df[sorted_columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to consider the pattern you expect.

You want A-B-A-A-B-A. So if you `concat` `df2` and `df1`, and assume columns indices `[0, 1, 2, 3, *4, *5]` (`*` denotes `df1` items), you want to reorder `[0, *4, 1, 2, *5, 3]`.

For this, you can do:

```
import numpy as np

n = len(df2) # 4
m = len(df1) # 2

a = np.arange(n+m)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

a = np.r_[np.delete(a, a[1::3]), a[1::3]]
# order in which to take values
# move 1, 4 to the end or the array
# array([0, 2, 3, 5, 1, 4])

np.argsort(a)
# sorted order
# array([0, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3])
```

Now, you just perform:

```
output = pd.concat([ciws, rws], axis=1)
output.iloc[:, np.argsort(a)]
```

and here you are:

```
       ipt_v1                          ipt_v2                    
            l          m          u         l         m         u
V7  24.251368  24.588074  24.924780  4.901619  4.958045  5.014471
V4  21.806257  22.116738  22.427219  4.665580  4.726775  4.787970
```

simpler example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list('BB'), range(4,6)).T
#    4  5
# 0  B  B

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list('AAAA'), range(4)).T
#    0  1  2  3
# 0  A  A  A  A

df3 = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1).iloc[:, np.argsort(a)]
#    0  4  1  2  5  3
# 0  A  B  A  A  B  A
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the columns from two dfs and append them alternately using itertools then reorder the coulmns in output df

```
import itertools
def combo(data1, data2):
    rws = data1
    ciws = data2
    
    rws.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['m'],rws.columns])
    rws = rws.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
    
    output = pd.concat([ciws, rws], axis=1)
    
    # alternating the columns
    rws_cols = list(rws.columns)
    ciws_cols = list(ciws.columns)
    cols =  [x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(ciws_cols,rws_cols)) if x]
    output = output[cols]

    output = (output[list(sum(zip(ciws.columns, rws.columns), ()))])
    return output

# call the function
output = combo(data1, data2)
print(output)
```