# Row-wise minimum of a DataFrame after applying a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
   Col1   Col2   Col3
0   7      11     17
1   13     12     15
2   19     23     14
3   22     19     21
```

I want to find the row-wise minimum after applying a function, returning the original values before the function was applied, somewhat like using the built-in `min` function in python with the `key` argument. E.g. if the function gives the absolute difference between the values of this DataFrame and a series `s`:

```
16
10
17
27
```

i.e. `abs(Col# - s)` then a new DataFrame containing the results of the function would look like:

```
   Col1   Col2   Col3
0   9      5      1
1   3      2      5
2   2      6      3
3   5      8      6
```

The row-wise minimum of this would then be a series looking like:

```
1
2
2
5
```

I want a series containing the corresponding values from the original DataFrame:

```
17
12
19
22
```

I'm not aware of any minimum-finding function in pandas that has a `key` argument like python's built-in function.

I have found a solution that requires iterating through the rows of the DataFrame `df` as follows:

```
l = []
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    l.append(min(row,key = lambda x: abs(x-s[idx])))
pandas.Series(l)
```

I've also considered applying the function to the DataFrame, then finding `idxmin` of each row:

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: abs(x-s))
s2 = df1.idxmin(1)
```

which should give `s2` as:

```
Col3
Col2
Col1
Col1
```

and then is there a way to select values from a DataFrame using column names from a series, i.e. using the column names from `s2`, return a series of values from `df` with the value of `Col3` from the 1st row, the value of `Col2` from the 2nd row, the value of `Col1` from the 3rd row, and the value of `Col1` from the 4th row? At the moment, the only way I know of also involves iteration:

```
l = []
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    l.append(row[s2[idx]])
pandas.Series(l)
```

Are there any better ways of achieving this besides what I've mentioned?

Dictionaries used to construct the DataFrame and Series used in the example:

```
data = {'Col1': [7, 13, 19, 22], 'Col2': [11, 12, 23, 19], 'Col3': [17, 15, 14, 21]}
s = {0: 16, 1: 10, 2: 17, 3: 27}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the underlying numpy array and [`numpy.choose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html):

```
s = pd.Series([16,10,17,27])

idx = np.argmin(abs(df.sub(s, axis=0)).values, axis=1)
# array([2, 1, 0, 0])

pd.Series(np.choose(idx, df.values.T), index=s.index)
# 0    17
# 1    12
# 2    19
# 3    22
# dtype: int64
```

Comment: `argmin`, `argsort`, you should apply for a patent like `frozenset` :)

Comment: @Corralien [you don't say? :p](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996823/16343464)

Comment: I found this solution to be fastest for my case

Comment: @oc yes numpy is usually the fastest ;)

Answer (score 1):

As `lookup` is now deprecated, you have to flatten your dataframe manually to retrieve one value per row with `loc`. The first line computes your operation and get the index of the minimum:

```
r = df.sub(sr, axis=0).abs().idxmin(axis=1)
df['min_val_with_key'] = df.unstack().loc[zip(r.values, r.index)].values
print(df)
print(r)

# Output of df
   Col1  Col2  Col3  min_val_with_key
0     7    11    17                17
1    13    12    15                12
2    19    23    14                19
3    22    19    21                22

# Output of r
0    Col3
1    Col2
2    Col1
3    Col1
dtype: object
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [7, 13, 19, 22],
                   'Col2': [11, 12, 23, 19],
                   'Col3': [17, 15, 14, 21]})

sr = pd.Series([16, 10, 17, 27])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the indices using idxmin and then just read the single values using loc and append them to a list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': {0: 7, 1: 13, 2: 19, 3: 22},
 'Col2': {0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 23, 3: 19},
 'Col3': {0: 17, 1: 15, 2: 14, 3: 21}})
series = pd.Series([16, 10, 17, 27])
df2 = df.subtract(series, axis=0).abs()

minima = df2.idxmin(axis=1)
result = []
for row, column in minima.iteritems():
    result.append(df.loc[row, column]) 
df_result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["minimum"])
```

The last part can also be done using a list comprehension:

```
minima = df2.idxmin(axis=1)
df_result = pd.DataFrame(
    [df.loc[row, column] for row, column in minima.iteritems()],
    columns=["minimum"]
    )
```